# coupling user that sign-in from gmail but also from facebook

Tags: facebook, authentication, gmail

My service allows sign-in from gmail, Facebook and other services.

Let's imagine it's only gmail and facebook -

is there an elegant way to understand that the same user that signed-in yesterday with gmail is the same user that today signed in with facebook?

and how should I handle the cases where the user is now loged-in to his gmail but not to his facebook, or he's now logged-in to both, etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to require the `email` extended permission from Facebook which will return the users email address.  Then assuming they used the same gmail address on Facebook, you would be able to match the 2 of them up because Gmail authentication can return the users email address as well. This is similar to how stackoverflow.com works, as you will notice they require the email extended permission when you first connect to facebook.